# Eclipse RCP: TableViewer setInput from another view

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I have several views in my RCP project.

In one view I have a `TableViewer`.

In another view I have a `JFrame` with a `Button`.

I want to update the data in the `TableViewer` using the `setInput()` method when I press the button in another view.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Initial input to the table viewer:

```
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new TableLabelProvider() );
tableViewer.setInput(TraceData.getTraceData());     // get realtime data
```

I add the listener to the tableViewer to listen to changes in the GUI

```
listener = new ISelectionListener() {
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection sel) {
       if (!(sel instanceof IStructuredSelection))
          return;
       IStructuredSelection ss = (IStructuredSelection) sel;
       Object o = ss.getFirstElement();
       if (o instanceof Book) // something else in place of Book
          tableViewer.setInput(TraceData.getSavedTraceData());
    }
 };

getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(listener);
```

And the problem is how to make it react to a button event in another view? That is how to brodcast the `JButton` press event and then listen to that event in this `TreeViewer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my RCP application, I have a View class which is extended by all others. In this View I have :

```
abstract void refresh();
```

Now, you have to use the refresh method of the view with the TableViewer.

```
@Override
public void refresh() {
    tableViewer.setInput(...);
    tableViewer.refresh();
}
```

And you have to call the refresh method from the button

How to access a view from anotherone.

```
final IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
final IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
try {
    if (page.getActivePart() != null) {
    viewTitle = page.getActivePart().getTitle();
    IViewPart view = page.showView(MainView.ID)  //id de la view in plugin.xml
    page.hideView(page.findView(SitesView.ID));
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I edited my post to clarify things.

Comment: I would use View view = (View) page.findView(View.ID); to access the view and then the refresh method. Worked for me. But may it's not the best way to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could not find the page.findView() method. And I also think listeners are the best way.

Comment: Ok just in case you need to access a view from its id. See my post I added some code.

Comment: Turns out that the [IEventBroker](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fe4%2Fcore%2Fservices%2Fevents%2FIEventBroker.html) is the best way to communicate with views, then I used setInput and refresh as you had mentioned, so +1 :)

Comment: Thx I am gonna look for the IEventBroker.

Comment: You can check this [Link](http://codeandme.blogspot.de/2013/08/using-event-broker-without-di.html)